# Transformar texto em negrito com php

Tags: php, jquery

Boa Noite, estou com um grande problema, é o seguinte, eu estou com um formulário de textarea para enviar textos ao banco de dados, e o que eu quero fazer é pegar um trecho ou uma palavra que está contido entre determinados caracteres e modificá-los para uma tag... Para esclarecer é Assim:

Vamos supor q quero pegar o texto que está dentro de dois traços(-): Esse é um -Texto- de Exemplo... E o resultado que quero é, sempre que o usuário colocar uma palavra ou um trecho do texto ente esses dois traços(-), quero trocá-los para:: Esse é um **Texto** de Exemplo.

Eu tentei com str_replace, mas não consegui o resultado desejado.

```
$text = $_POST['publicacaoText'];
$publicacaoStrip = str_replace("/*", "<b>", $text);
$publicacaoStrip = str_replace("*/", "</b", $publicacaoStrip);
```

Assim até dá certo, maaas tipo, se eu colocar duas vezes seguidas assim:: /*Breno*/ /*Castro*/... Ele faz o que eu quero, Mas Não adiciona o Espalo entre as duas palavras, ou seja, queria fazer o sistema de negrito e itálico que nem o WhatsApp *-Breno-* **+Castro+**, e percebi que aqui no stackoverflow também tem o mesmo sistema. Por Favor se alguém puder me ajudaaar, agradeçooo demaais velho.

Aviso também que já tentei assim:

```
$publicacaoStrip = str_replace("-$text-", "<b>$text</b>", $publicacaoStrip);
```

OU

```
$publicacaoStrip = str_replace("-".$text."-", "<b>$text</b>", $publicacaoStrip);
```

E obviamente não deu certo kkkkk Foi até idiotice ter testado assim, mas fiz pra ter certeza kkkkkk

Por favor pessoal, me ajudeem, tô precisando bastanteee mesmo

Se alguém souber como fazer isso também com JQuery também, mas preferencial é com PHP por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Texto em questão.
$publicacaoStrip = 'teste -teste- arr-o-z';

// Expressão regular para negrito.
$reNegrito = '/-([^-]+?)-/';

// Expressão regular para itálico.
$reItalico = '/\*([^\*]+?)\*/';

// Sintaxe de substituição de expressão regular, para negrito.
$replacementNegrito = '<b>$1</b>';

// Sintaxe de substituição de expressão regular, para itálico.
$replacementItalico = '<i>$1</i>';

// Opera a substituição das ocorrências da(s) expressão(ões) regular(es) pelo seu substituto.
$publicacaoStrip = preg_replace(array($reNegrito, $reItalico),
    array($replacementNegrito, $replacementItalico), 
    $publicacaoStrip);

// Ecoa e termina a execução do php.
die($publicacaoStrip);
```

Comment: Cara, muito Boom, me ajudoou muitooo, mas por favor me diz uma coisa, tipo, você colocou para quando tiver o texto entre (-) ele substituir para (<b>), certo até aí beleza, e se eu quiser colocar uma função a mais, tipo, o (-) fica em negrito e o (*) fica em italico, o que tenho que modificar no codigo, teria como me ajudar?

Comment: Editado com as mudanças propostas.

Answer (score 1):

Galera muitooooo Obrigadooo pela atenção, e agradeço mt ao @Marcelo_Uchimura, mt obrigado msm cara, me ajudoou muitoo, eu tava com mt duvida pq Nn entendo bem sobre a função preg_replace, aproveitando, se alguém puder me explicar mais sobre essa função ou algum artigo bem explicativo sobre ela e puder me indicar, pfv, agradeço mt, e é isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda mesmo, e consegui fazer oq eu pretendia

```
$text = $_POST['publicacaoText'];
    $publicacaoStrip = strip_tags($text);

    // Expressão regular.
    $re = array('/\*([^*]+)\*/', '/-([^-]+?)-/');

    // Sintaxe de substituição de expressão regular.
    $replacement = array('<u>$1</u>', '<b>$1</b>');

    // Opera a substituição das ocorrências da expressão regular pelo seu substituto.
    $publicacaoStrip = preg_replace($re, $replacement, $publicacaoStrip);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se quer por apenas o espaço entre elas acho que isso resolve:

```
$text = $_POST['publicacaoText'];
// aqui ele quebrará $text toda vez que achar */
$palavras = explode("*/", $text);
// aqui contará as celulas de $palavras
$nP = count($palavras);
// para verificar se houve o post de uma palavra composta ex: /*Breno*/ /*Castro*/, se for apenas uma palavra ele fará essa substituição apenas para uma..
if(isset($palavras[1])){ 
   //caso a célula 1 for inicializada e não for vazia, esse for trocará toda /* por <b> e */ por </b>, sempre irá colocar no mesmo lugar da onde ele pegou a palavra.
   for($i = 0; $i < $nP; $i++){
      $palavras[$i] = str_replace("/*", "<b>", $palavras[$i]);
      $palavras[$i] = str_replace("*/", "</b", $palavras[$i]);       
   }
} else {
  $palavra = str_replace("/*", "<b>", $palavras[0]);
  $palavra = str_replace("*/", "</b", $palavra);
}
```

Daí o espaço você coloca quando for dar um echo nas palavras, isso é uma solução bem fraquinha, pra um caso urgente como o seu, acredito que dá pra simplificar e melhorar mais esse código que fiz.

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo cara.
Não tá fazendo a substituição, tá aparecendo o texto Cru /*Texto*/

Comment: O que eu quero é Selecionar o texto entre *$text* e modificá-lo para <b>$text</b>

igual ao WhatsApp e o próprio site do stackoverflow

Comment: Então, testei aqui enviando $text = '/*Jorge*/ /*Silva*/'  e retornou <b>Jorge</b> <b>Silva</b>.

Comment: Pois no meu deu erro.
E queria ao invés de usar /*texto*/, poder utilizar só '* texto *'

Comment: @BrenoCastro Como vc quer afinal?

Comment: Quero o sistema de Negrito do WhatsApp
Que ao colocar uma palavra ente (*) -> *Texto* ele transforma a palavra em negrito

Comment: Leandro, mt obg tbm, vou ultilizar teu método pra poder adicionar o espaçoo, vllw cara